# Regex to identify float or int only for currency

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use regex to ensure the input is a number or a float. If the dollar sign is entered by the user, I want javascript to remove it and return true. If a comma is entered by the user return false.

This is what I tried (however it always returns false):

```
var validAmount = new RegExp('/[^0-9.]/g');
validAmount.test(numberAmount); 

if(!validAmount.test(parseFloat(numberAmount))){
   alert("bad Amount");
}
```

Desired output:

```
Input: 232 //output: true
Input: 1212.23 //output:true
Input: $12.23 //(remove $ sign and output:true)
Input: a23 //output:false
Input: 1,000 //(output:false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex may work for you:

```
amount.replace(/^\$?([\d]+\.?[\d]*)$/, '$1');
```

By which I mean it will return the valid string (when valid input) or nothing (false) when invalid.

Comment: why `^?` ? it means matching from the beginning of the string is optional?

Comment: I am getting an invalid quantifier error... `var validAmount = new RegExp('/^?\$([\d]+?\.[\d]*)$/g');`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Yes, please use the updated answer - there was a typo. see how you go. cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still getting invalid quantifier error after edit.  `var validAmount = new RegExp('/^\$?([\d]+\.?[\d]*)$/g');`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend I think you are not meant to use '' in JS for regexes

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for the reply, this worked as expected and satisfied all conditions ;D I appreciate the help!

Comment: does that regex literally read, '$' is optional at the beginning, followed by one or more number which may be followed by a `.` which instead will be followed by 0 or more number and we reach the end of string? trying to learn regex more!

Comment: Hm, I get `'abcd'.replace(/^\$?([\d]+\.?[\d]*)$/, '$1');` returning `'abcd'`, not empty.

Comment: @rps Hi. yes, that's exactly what it means. Your regex would work as well... and good point about the fact that mine will accept "123." (which may or may not be what is needed). Also note yours will accept ".123" (similar deal). All the best.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, fair enough - that is what would happen. Perhaps I should not have used the "replace" in my answer - my focus was the regex which would match the pattern the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for something like `/^(\$?(\d+(\.\d+)*)?|.*)$/`;

```
> exp = /^(\$?(\d+(\.\d+)*)?|.*)$/

> '232'.replace(exp, '$2');
'232'

> '1212.23'.replace(exp, '$2');
'1212.23'

> '$12.23'.replace(exp, '$2');
'12.23'

> 'a23'.replace(exp, '$2');
''

> '1,000'.replace(exp, '$2');
''
```

Comment: the thing is that the OP doesn't even want to use "replace"... they want to use "test". If the do this then their code won't work - it'll let anything through. They were using replace then they changed it after I finished.

Comment: @d'alar'cop The part where he wants `$` removed points to a replace, and the return value of "no match" is falsy, so usable right inside an `if` expression. Just added this as an alternative solution anyway, I know the question already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the ".*"... so anything will pass unless it differs slightly from the desired pattern, right?

Comment: @d'alar'cop The .* only takes effect if the first part of the pattern does not match, which leaves $2 empty. In other words, anything that does not match the desired pattern will return an empty string.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that a few moments after I left my comment. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\$?(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$/
```

This may work too.

```
var regex=/^\$?(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$/;
alert(regex.test("232"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhTq2/