# Restrict entering anything except decimal number in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need to allow user to enter only decimal value. The following is my HTML code for the input field.

```
<label for="conversion-factor">Conversion Factor:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="conversion-factor" formControlName="conversionFactor" (keypress)="keyPressConversionFactor($event)">
        <div *ngIf="Conversion.controls['conversionFactor'].errors && Conversion.controls['conversionFactor'].touched" class="err-msg">
          Conversion Factor is required
        </div>
```

My .ts file has implemented the keyPressConversionFactor event as below

```
keyPressConversionFactor(event: any) {
const pattern = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/; // //[0 - 9] /;

let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
if (event.keyCode != 8 && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Using this, I let user to enter only numbers. But I want user to enter decimal number incuding the dot. Above code doesnt allow to type dot (".")

Comment: Regex for currency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172765/regex-to-identify-float-or-int-only-for-currency. The problem OP has is not only with regex. Maybe something like this could do the job: https://jsfiddle.net/yro3oxw8/

Comment: @dfsq what other problem have you identified and where is that solved in your fiddle?

Comment: @dfsq With that JSFiddle I managed to input `.0` by entering `0.0` then backspaced the 1st 0. The input then blocked all other key presses and I couldn't correct it. You can also still copy-paste values too like `0.000000`. It also disallows using the arrow keys for moving the caret around. Not user friendly!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of restricting input. Either by being pessimistic or optimistic.

A pessimistic example would be disallow entering any letters for ZIP codes or credit card numbers (i.e. each character typed needs to be completely valid).

The most optimistic example would be like entering an email, but waiting till the email input losses focus before validating/restricting. Someone might like typing emails 1st by `@.com` then going back to add `me@.com` then finishing with `me@example.com`.

What you need is a little of both. As the user types, check the most strict format `0.0` but if it doesn't match that, try `0.` then `.0` to see if they match. If they do, your being optimistic that the user hasn't' finished yet. Then once the input loses focus, test against the strict format `0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following RegEx:

This regex allows you to pass decimal number with 2 precision points.

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?

\d+(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Comment: Not what the OP wants: `/[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/.test("0.000000") // true` nor `/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/.test("0.0000000") // true` I'd go for multiple simpler RegExps in combination.

Comment: And you'd still need to valid against the strict RegExp upon losing focus